# No water in door of Samsung French door style refrigerator

Tags: water, doors, refrigerator

Have a Samsung RF24J9960S4 refrigerator - french door style with soda dispenser.

Over several weeks the water dispenser reduced its water volume.  New filter or no filter made no difference.

Now there is no water dispensing at all or a few drips at a time.  The water pressure if fine up through the hose above the door.  I have taken off the connector to the door and trigger the water and it shoots out quite a bit, so it is nothing with the refrigerator.  The blockage is in the door.  I can hear it try to work when I depress the water pedal, but it just slowly drips out.

The soda water was dispensing fairly well, but now I think it has run dry and can't fill the soda water reservoir either.

I can't find anything on the web about the components/layout of the door, how to open it up, or what I can do.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Did you call Samsung, you need a service.

Comment: Have you read the owner's manual.  I'd think the instructions on refilling the soda dispenser would be there.  As far as the water, it sounds like a blockage of some sort.  Either take the unit apart and fix it or contact a service technician.

Comment: @jwh20  either blockage or a stuck valve (which is a block, but needs replacement rather than a cleanout)

Comment: Thanks for comments.  As suggested, I assume it is a stuck valve, I was hoping there was info somewhere on what the components inside the door and how to access them.  I removed the two screws that are visible, which allows the door controls to drop very slightly, but am hesitant to try to force anything as I don't want to break the plastic.  Maybe I will call this time and watch how the technician accesses the front.  Thanks for your input.